# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable / if( count($query) ) {

Tags: php, opencart-3

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable on line 5

```
<?php
class ModelSliderTGsuperstarRevolutionSlider extends Model {        
public function getSlider($id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREFIX."tg_superstar_revolution_slider WHERE id='".$id."'");
    if( count($query) ) {
        foreach($query->rows as $row) {
            $output = array(
                'id' => $row['id'],
                'settings' => unserialize($row['settings']),
                'content' => unserialize($row['content'])
            );
            return $output;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
?>
```

https://hcforklift.ch/

How can I fix this error?
Many thanks!
JJ

Comment: What have you tried so far to fix this?

Comment: Additionally be warned that this SQL query is widely open for SQL injection - please have a look at prepared statements

Comment: Are you trying to count the rows? If that is the case then RTM

Comment: `if( is_array($qquery) && count($query) ) {`

Comment: Configure your PHP-server, so that it doesn`t show error-statements on a livesystem (it seems to be one). On your developmachine this is ok but never live you make it vulnerable by showing unwanted issues to others.

Comment: It simply means what it says: `$query` isn't an array. It probably is `false` or `NULL` because your query failed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Codeigniter?

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREFIX."tg_superstar_revolution_slider WHERE id='".$id."'")
```

In this line you aren't fetching any row, you are just querying aganist the database

Add the get and result method if you are using Codeigniter.

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREFIX."tg_superstar_revolution_slider WHERE id=?", [$id])->get()->result();
```